# How to use trpc query if input data is not available at mount?

Tags: trpc.io

I have a component with a list of conversations and i want to load a specific conversation on click. The problem is that I have to initialise the second trpc query at mount and I dont have the required data yet. Any help would be highly apriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `enabled` flag of `useQuery`:

```
const requiredDataIsAvailable = false

trpc.useQuery(['todos'], {
  // query will only fetch data if the following variable evaluates to true
  enabled: requiredDataIsAvailable,
})
```

Only if `enabled` is `true` (= you got the required data for the query), it will fetch the data from the server.

Docs:

- https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/guides/disabling-queries
- https://trpc.io/docs/react-queries